# How to access {% url "name" %} inside 'include' tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I can't figure out how to get value of {% url "name" %} inside another `{% %}` tag. In my case its `include`

```
{% include "file" with next={% url "name" %} %}
```

This doesn't work. Do you know what to do? I would surround the `{% include..` by `{% with` but it would cause the same problem.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a `url` tag in jinja2, so what are you actually using?..

Comment: Seems to me that the question is about the django template language only, and the jinja2 tag shouldn't really be there, but oh well.

Comment: Sorry, I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick answer for django templates:

```
{% url "name" as my_url_context_var %}
{% include "file" with next=my_url_context_var %}
```

Lengthier explanation:

You cannot nest `{% … %}` or `{{ … }}`. The moment you open `{{ … }}`, you can only use context variables inside, optionally combined with template filters. Inside a `{% … %}`, you can only use whatever the tag you are using recognizes, but in general, that will be just a few arguments, some of which are static words (such as the `as` in the `url` above, or the `with` in the `include`), and often you can also access template variables and filters just like inside `{{ … }}`.

I'm not that familiar with jinja, but it seems that its [`include`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#include) doesn't support the same kind of variable passing as django's `include` does, so here's an idea of what it might look like with jinja:

```
{% set next=url('name') %}
{% include "file" %}
```